# Office.Interop for document format conversion

Tags: server-side, office-interop

I have generated documents ( in Docx, Xlsx, PDF formats) using ReportViewer.WebForms. 
Problem is, I need few additional formats (Html and Rtf), so i made conversions using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. Basicly it's opens file and saves it in different format.

Whats need to be done in server side (besides installing word, only word is enough?)?I know it's bad practice, but are there any other solutions?

P.S.Commercial librarys like Aspose.Words are awesome, but project is too small to buy license.
P.P.S. Those two formats will be rearly used, so performance is not very big issue. Documents quite simple, no more than simple 3 tables.

Comment: It's not just a bad practice, it doesn't work reliably. That code was written for a desktop environment, and not a multiple-threaded server environment.

Comment: I know that. Believe me i know that. Thats why pushing my PM to get rid off these two formats. But meanwhile i still got to come up with somekind solution.

Comment: Office Interop is not a solution in this case, unless you find unexplained crashes and memory corruption to be acceptable.